# Watson Assistant - How to get size of specific entities

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-dialog, watson-assistant

For example I have 3 different entities

```
@action = eat,run,walk
@person = Michael, John, Fred 
@emotion = angry,sad,happy
```

I want to count user entered action and person entities

```
If bot recognizes
entities['action'].size() + entities['person'].size() > 2
```

Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the scenario or question? Could you provide more context? You seem to know how to get to the size.

Comment: how can I add the size of two entities using the condition
the example above is not working so I was trying to look for another way

I can only achieve this by creating a context variable that holds the count
and with the help of multiple response

Comment: I have trouble reading your comment. Could you separate sentences by comma or period / full stop? Do you want to add two values before comparing? Where do you place that condition?

Comment: Sorry for that.. 
Yes i was trying to add 2 values of entities size, I want to place it on the condition (If Bot Recognizes)

Comment: basically it doesn't continue adding the 2 entity size if one is null, Is there a way to add it even if one entity is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To account for one of the entities not being recognized, you can use ternary operator `<Expression> ? <what_to_do_when_true> : <what_to_do_when_false>`.

So, in your example the condition would look like this: 
`((entities['action'] != null ? entities['action'].size() : 0) + (entities['action'] != null ? entities['person'].size() : 0)) > 2`

When one of the entity is not recognized (`null`), the value counted will be `0`.